# Methods for solving Diophantine $Ax + by = y^2$, or others with only one second-degree term?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

To be precise, I am curious about the equation

$$Ax+by=y^2$$

where all variables are positive integers and $A$ is given as some fixed constant.

I know you can do it with a Pell equation/continued fraction convergents, so to be clear, I'm wondering if there are any other ways to solve this form without brute force---I suspect there aren't, but would love to be corrected, as this is not really my area.

I've googled pretty extensively and was surprised that I couldn't find this already addressed somewhere. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Discriminant of square will be promising!

Comment: $$x=\frac{y(y-b)}{A}$$ There may be some problems???? Can not share?

Comment: @Ghartal Isn't that what you would ordinarily have to use convergents to find?

Comment: @mindloss I thought that $b$ is a constant too!